# customised message is not displayed (using Jsf and primeface3.3)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am creating a demo project using primeface 3.3 and JSF, in which if a user doesn't fill a required field then it should show a message. Here is my code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
   <title> growl</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>  

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  

      <p:panel > 
        <h:panelGrid columns="3"> 

            <h:outputText value="Your Name: *" />   
            <p:inputText value="#{someBean}" required="true" label="Name" requiredMessage="User Name Requireds"/>  
       <h:messages style="color:red;margin:5px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton value="Save"    action="success" />  
    </p:panel>  

</h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

when clicking to save button without filling user name it doesn't show the required message

Comment: `value="#{someBean}"` typo ? if not , change it into `value="#{someBean.someValue}"` , also change `action="success"` into action="{someBean.someVoidMethod}"

Comment: I have bean and method and i tested on it but...still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` sends by default an ajax request wherein by default the entire form is executed (as in `process="@form"`), but by default actually *nothing* will be updated (as in `update=""`).

If you want to update the UI on complete of the ajax request, then you need to explicitly specify the `update` attribute. For example, this updates the entire form:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="@form" />
```

And this updates only a specific component:

```
<h:messages id="messages" ... />
<p:commandButton ... update="messages" />
```

You can alternatively also use PrimeFaces own `<p:messages>` which supports auto-updating.

```
<p:messages ... autoUpdate="true" />
<p:commandButton ... />
```